# Razor Page .net6 returns 'client has disconnected' when attempting redirection

Tags: authentication, redirect, razor, .net-6.0, disconnection

Using claims authentication and trying to ensure that some pages require that user is logged in. Seems no matter what I try the VS debugger always stops with:

Client has disconnected.
COMException: An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection. (0x800704CD)

I've tried several different methods to redirect:
-- On the page:
`@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Index")`

-- In code behind:

```
`public IActionResult OnGet()
 {
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         return Page();
     }
         return RedirectToPage("/Index");
         (Also
           - return new RedirectToPageResult("/Index");
           - return Redirect("/Index")
         )  

 }`
```

If the user is authenticated, it works just fine.
But if not, all attempts above give me the same error.
-- if I click Continue in VS, it goes on to the Index page.

What am I doing wrong?